# unable to create new user in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to create a new user in mysql 5.6, but while executing the query i am getting an error. please help.

```
mysql> create user dsuser@'%' indentified by 'Passw0rd';<br></b>
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'indentified by 'Passw0rd'' at line 1
```

Comment: The keyword is spelled **`IDENTIFIED`**, not **`INDENTIFIED`**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE USER 'dsuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Passw0rd';
```

Don't forget the quotes around your username as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
create user 'dsuser'@'%' indentified by 'Passw0rd';
```

Comment: @Jens - Quotes around the username, because it's needed.

Comment: @JoelCox please add the explanation to your answer.